# Validate array with 2 values

Tags: javascript, arrays, yup

I'm trying to validate that an array has 2 specific values, something like:

```
['foo', 'bar']
```

I feel like the closest I came to the answer is something like this:

```
Yup.array()
  .of(Yup.mixed().oneOf(['foo', 'bar']))
  .min(2)
  .max(2)
```

But this would also pass `['foo', 'foo']` and `['bar', 'bar']`

Comment: `Yup.mixed().oneOf([['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'foo']])`? Or add your own method using [`addMethod`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#yupaddmethodschematype-schema-name-string-method--schema-void) and do something like `Yup.array().containsInAnyOrder(['foo', 'bar'])`.

Comment: My little piece of advice, do not use frameworks/libraries for such simple tasks. It will add greatly to your skill to try using plain javascript. From ES6 era on, js is a wonder for functional stuff like that

Answer (score 1):

As a variant you can use Yup `test` function, which allow you to manipulate with current field value and another form field values. On this example we check is field value has duplicates like `['foo', 'foo']` and then check if there are no duplicated or every value of field array includes `foo` or `bar`:

```
Yup.array()
  .test('contains', 'Error message here', function (value) {
      let hasDuplicate = value.some((val, i) => value.indexOf(val) !== i);
      return !hasDuplicate && value.every(el => ['foo', 'bar'].includes(el));
   })
  .min(2)
  .max(2)
```

Here you can find more insformcation about `test` function: https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema

Comment: That would allow any array of length two where one of the values is either `'foo'` or `'bar'`.

Comment: but it was a question. It could include same values

Comment: No, the OP is saying specifically that this was a *problem* with their existing implementation. Also yours would allow e.g. `['bar', 'baz']`, which contains an element that shouldn't be valid.

Comment: Now this *only* has the same problem as the OP's implementation.

Comment: `['foo', 'bar'].every(el => ['foo', 'bar'].includes(el))` returns true. `['foo', 'baz'].every(el => ['foo', 'bar'].includes(el))` returns false. What a problem?

Comment: `['foo', 'foo'].every(el => ['foo', 'bar'].includes(el))` is `true`...

Comment: Ah, it shouldn't pass?

Comment: Please re-read the question. The OP's current code also allows `['foo', 'foo']` and `['bar', 'bar']`, and *that's the problem they're trying to solve*.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that, generally, Code only answers without context or explanation as to how/why your solution addresses the OP's issue are frowned upon. Conditions where your solution works vs when it would not apply should be included where applicable. Long term value and opportunities for learning are absent in code-only answers. Hence future visitors are unlikely to glean much insight to apply to their own code issues. Keep quality of SO Answers high, and increase your chances of getting upvotes, by editing to include more info, caveats, context, and/or explanations to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function for this too.
what i understood is you are looking for exactly 2 variables in an array.
here is what i tried

```
function find(arr,first,second){
let temp=false;
if(arr.includes(first)&&arr.includes(second)){
temp=true;
}
return temp;
}

find(["foo","bar"],"foo","bar");
```

if you are looking for an array of exactly same length then you can have length check too in function.
the function will look like

```
function find(arr,first, second){
  let temp=false;
  if(arr.length!=2)
    return false
   if(arr.includes(first)&&arr.includes(second)){
   temp=true;
   }
  return temp;
}

find(["foo","bar"],"foo","bar");
```